# SurvivorRatio flag of JVM does not work?

Tags: java, jvm

The document from Oracle writes "The `SurvivorRatio` parameter controls the size of the two survivor spaces. For example, `-XX:SurvivorRatio=6` sets the ratio between each survivor space and eden to be 1:6, each survivor space will be one eighth of the young generation", but it **does not work** in my case below.

**The JVM Flags I set:**
[image]

**The JVM heap infomation:**
[image]

**The gcutil output every 1 second:**
[image]

Here are the questions:

1. From Space capacity : Eden Space capacity = 4.5 : 824.5 which is not
   1:6, so where is wrong?
2. Why the switch between S0U and S1U changes
   (Minor GC) so frequently which causes high cpu load.

Comment: Perhaps you need the `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` option…

Comment: @Holger it did not work :(

Comment: According to your answer, it *did* work?

Comment: @Holger yes, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

`-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is enabled by default, and is incompatible with `-XX:SurvivorRatio=n`. After when I used `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` to disable adaptive size policy, it works now.